# import form text file to gridview c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview, datagridview

I'm trying to import data from text file to grid view  using the blew code :

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
using (System.IO.TextReader tr = File.OpenText((@"d:\\My File3.log")))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {

        string[] items = line.Trim().Split(' ');
        if (dt.Columns.Count == 0)
        {
            // Create the data columns for the data table based on the number of items
            // on the first line of the file
            for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column" + i, typeof(string)));
        }
        dt.Rows.Add(items);

    }
    //show it in gridview 
    this.GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    this.GridView1.DataBind();
```

My file is like :

A B C

E F D C C

E D D D

D P

Then I get the following error

> Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table in c# application

Comment: you are adding columns for each line. you should add only once.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have create `columns` of your `table` based on your **first line**, but in **second line have more column then first line**. Please check below code it will work based on `MAX` column.

CODE:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

List<string[]> list = new List<string[]>();
int maxItem = 0;
using (System.IO.TextReader tr = File.OpenText((@"d:\\My File3.log")))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {

        string[] items = line.Trim().Split(' ');

        if (maxItem <= items.Count())
        {
            maxItem = items.Count();
        }

        list.Add(items);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < maxItem; i++)
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column" + i, typeof(string)));

    foreach (var items in list)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(items);
    }

    //show it in gridview 
    this.GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    this.GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

In your data some line have `empty`. So, you have to check `empty` line in your code.

Output of your data:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should add new column when required number of columns (after `Split(' ')`) is *greater* than actual (`dt.Columns.Count`) one:

```
  // File.ReadLines is easier to read and maintain
  var items = File
   .ReadLines(@"d:\My File3.log") // single \ since we have verbatim string @ 
 //.Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)) // if you want to remove empty lines 
   .Select(line => line.Trim().Split(' '));

  DataTable dt = new DataTable();

  foreach (var line in items) {
    // Do we want extra columns?
    while (line.Length > dt.Columns.Count)
      dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn($"Column {dt.Columns.Count}", typeof(string)));

    dt.Rows.Add(line);
  }

  GridView1.DataSource = dt;
  GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: @marwen1: You are welcome! Hope, you've got the idea